# When to use "and" or "or" when providing a list

Tags: conjunctions, logic

I know this is very simple, but it might be confusing me.

if I say;

> 1. It can be done using a search algorithm such as A, B **or** C.
> 2. It can be done using a search algorithm such as A, B **and** C.

Note: for the simplicity **let us assume A,B,C are the names of the algorithms**.

Can I use both **or** and **and** for that case? Are both grammatically correct?

Comment: I'm under the impression that both are grammatical, but the "2" case is semantically incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise more on the usage of the first one. Since you are finally going to use only one algorithm for your search (as depicted by "*using a search algorithm*") you'd be using **or** in your sentence.

On the other hand, if you are choosing/providing a list, using **and** will be correct in that situation. For this, the construction should be something like

> It can be done using an algorithm among the class of A, B and C.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is a difference between the two sentences. When you use *or* you mean one of them, but when you use *and* you mean all of them. It depends on your situation which one of them you need.

Comment: The exception would be when you're describing the contents of a list, e.g., "Algorithms that are known to work in this situation are A, B and C."